# If A⊂B,prove that $A^\circ⊂B^\circ$ and $cl (A) ⊂ cl(B)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

For the open sets,  $A ⊂ B,  B^\circ ⊂ B,  A^\circ ⊂ A$  We can say $A^\circ ⊂ B$ ..not sure what to do next.

For the closed sets, $A ⊂ cl(A)  , B ⊂ cl (B)$ then $A ⊂ cl (B)$ and I'm not sure what do next?

Am I on the right track or I need to use the definitions for the proof?

Comment: The last step is to realize that $A^\circ$ is open and $B^\circ$ is the union of all open subsets of $B$.

Comment: The question is not clear to me.

Comment: @Stefan, how come B^o is the union open subsets of B and it is a subset of B?? I don't get it.

Comment: That's the definition of the interior. Or at least one possible definition.

Comment: For the question about closure see: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121236/if-a-is-a-subset-of-b-then-the-closure-of-a-is-contained-in-the-closure-of-b

Answer (score 3):

Well ...

> ... or [do] I need to use the definitions for the proof?

yes. There might be some shortcut (which then would use the definition), but even then it's a good practice to use the definitions.

So, if you don't want to miss the practice, don't read the following spoiler.

In the **first exercise** it's near an immediate deduction from the very definitions:

\begin{align*}
   A^° = \bigcup_{U\in\mathcal{O}(X), U\subseteq A} U
\end{align*}

therefore:

\begin{align*}
   x \in A^° \Rightarrow \exists U \in \mathcal{O}(X): U\subseteq A\wedge x \in U
\end{align*}

and since $A \subseteq B$ it holds that $\exists U \in \mathcal{O}(X): U\subseteq A\subseteq B\wedge x \in U$, so $x \in B^°$.

Even in the **second exercise** it's just a small step -- but you may want to go by contradiction to keep it simple:

\begin{align*}
   x \notin \bigcap_{C\in\mathcal{C}(X), B \subseteq C} \Rightarrow \exists C \in \mathcal{C}(X) : B \subseteq C \wedge x \in C
\end{align*}

and since $A\subseteq B$, also $A \subseteq C$ and therefore $x \notin cl(A)$.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the definitions. I assume you are talking about subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let us prove $A^\circ \subset B^\circ$. Let $x\in A^\circ$. Then there is $\epsilon>0$ such that $B(x,\epsilon) \subset A\subset B$. Therefore $x\in B^\circ$.

Now the other part. First $A\subset B\subset \mathrm{cl}(B)$. The closure of $A$ is the intersection of all closed sets containing $A$. Since $\mathrm{cl}(B)$ *is* a closed set containing $A$, we get $\mathrm{cl}(A)\subset \mathrm{cl}(B)$.

Answer (score 1):

$ x \in A^\circ $ <=> there exists an open set $O_x$ containing $x$ in $A$. So we have $O_x \subset A \subset B$. Hence, by definition, $x \in B^{\circ}$.

For the other part we follows from the fact that : ${B^C}^\circ \subset {A^C}^\circ$.

Complement of these sets are closures of $B$ and $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
You can use the following equivalent definitions:
$A^o$ is the largest open set contained within $A$ and $cl(A)$ is the smallest closed set containing $A$. Have you proved these already / seen these yet?

Comment: No, I haven't. Are those theorems? All I have learned so far is the definition of open sets and closed sets.

Comment: I am sure the other answers have solved your query. However I also urge you to show that the above statements are equivalent to whatever definitions you know of. Walter Rudin is a good source. The aforementioned definition is useful in your problem for it solves it instantly. Care to try first and see how?

Comment: The definition you mentioned is quite helpful and makes things easier. I already did it using the definition after I posted my question.I got similar proof to the ones posted here. I'll definitely check out the book though it is very hard to understand. I wish there was a simpler one.