# Verification of proof that if $S$ is connected then the closure of $S$ is connected.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, proof-verification

I attempted to prove this theorem by contrapositive. Suppose $\overline{S}$ 
is disconnected. Then $\overline{S}=A\cup B$ such that $\overline{A}\cap B=A\cap \overline{B}=\varnothing$ and $A$ and $B$ are both nonempty. It follows that since $S\subseteq \overline{S}$, $S\subseteq A\cup B$. If $S$ is closed then the theorem follows trivially, so we will consider $S$ not closed. If $S\subset A\cup B$, then $S\subset A$, $S\subset B$, or $S$ contains some elements from $A$ and 
some from $B$. Suppose $S\subset A$, then $\overline{S}\subset \overline{A}$, and therefore there must be a $p\in\overline{S}$ that is also in $\overline{A}$ and $B$ since $B$ is nonempty and $\overline{S}=A\cup B$. But this contradicts $\overline{A}\cap B=\varnothing$. The same arguments holds for $S\subset B$.

Therefore it must be the case that $S$ contains elements of $A$ and $B$. Define the following sets,

$C=\{p : p\in S\cap A\}$

$D=\{q :q\in S\cap B\}$.

Then $S=C\cup D$. Consier $\overline{C}\cap D$. If $p\in \overline{C}\cap D$, then $p\in \overline{A}\cap B$. Another contradiction. The same argument holds for $C\cap \overline{D}$. Therefore $S=C\cup D$ with 
$\overline{C}\cap D=C\cap \overline{D}=\varnothing$. Thus, by contrapositive, if $S$ is connected then $\overline{S}$ is connected.

Comment: "If $S$ is closed then the theorem follows trivially, so we will consider $S$ open." — This should be "consider $S$ not closed."

Comment: What if $S $ is neither closed nor open?

Comment: I had not considered $S$ neither open nor closed explicitly. Although once I move on from $S$ being open, or as angryavian noted, $S$ not being closed, then the rest of the proof seems to be valid for $S$ neither open nor closed.

Comment: Not considering  the case when  $S$ is neither closed nor open would be a serious flaw in the proof. Why don't you edit your attempt?

Comment: Why not write $C=S\cap A$ and $D=S\cap B$ ?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, I thought that because I did not use the fact that $S$ is not closed going forward in the proof, that it should still hold if $S$ is in fact neither open nor closed. For it would still be not closed in this case.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, I guess I went a little over board

Answer (score 2):

Instead of with separated subsets, work with non-trivial clopen sets (it's equivalent): suppose $C$ is a non-empty clopen subset of $\overline{S}$; being open it intersects $S$ non-emptily, so $C \cap S$ is non-empty clopen in $S$. As $S$ is connected, $C \cap S= S$, or equivalently $S \subseteq C$. It follows that $\overline{S} \subseteq \overline{C}=C$ and so $C=\overline{S}$ and $\overline{S}$ is connected.

Yet another alternative: suppose $f: \overline{S} \to 2=(\{0,1\}, \tau_{\text{discr}})$ is continuous; we need to show it's constant. $f\restriction_S: S \to 2$ must be constant by connectedness of $S$ and as $S$ is dense in $\overline{S}$ and the space $2$ is Hausdorff, we get that $f$ is constant on $S$ as it coincides with a constant map on a dense subset. QED.

Or if you insist on separated sets: Suppose that $\overline{S}= A \cup B$, a separation.

Then $S = (S \cap A) \cup (S \cap B)$ and the intersection sets are still separated, of course. So, as $S$ is connected, one of them is empty, say $S \cap B=\emptyset$ and the other equals $S$ so $S \cap A=S$.

But then $S \subseteq A$, hence $\overline{S} \subseteq \overline{A} \subseteq \overline{S}\setminus B \subseteq A$, which shows that $B$ must be empty and we're done.

Comment: Does working with non-trivial clopen sets cover the case when $S$ is neither open nor closed?

Comment: @dallas2019 A space $X$ is connected iff it has no non-trivial (not $\emptyset$, not $X$) clopen set. This also holds for subspaces in the subspace topology.

Comment: I have not seen that before. In the first sentence do you mean no non-trivial clopen subsets? Thank you.

Comment: @dallas2019 I assume a non-empty clopen subset and show it's the whole space (i.e. $\overline{S}$); that's the same as showing there is no non-trivial one.

Answer (score 0):

The OP is using the following characterization of a disconnected space $X$,

> $X$ cannot be written as the union of two non-empty separated sets (sets for which each is disjoint from the other's closure).

(see this [wikilink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Formal_definition)).

Of course a $\text{<NOT Disconnected>}$ space $X$ is called a connected space.

In the next section we directly answer the OP's question using this characterization as the definition.

---

Proposition: If $\overline{S}$ is disconnected then $S$ is disconnected.
Proof
Suppose $\overline{S}$ 
is disconnected. Then $\overline{S}=A\cup B$ such that $\overline{A}\cap B=A\cap \overline{B}=\emptyset$ and $A$ and $B$ are both nonempty. Since $A \cap B \subset \overline{A} \cap B = \emptyset$, clearly the subsets $A$ and $B$
constitute a 2-block [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) of $\overline{S}$.

If $S \subset A$, then $\overline{S} \subset \overline{A}$ (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/121236/432081)). But then since $\overline{A}\cap B=\emptyset$,  $\,\overline{S}\cap B=\emptyset$, contradicting the premise that $\{A,B\}$ is a 2-block partition of $\overline{S}$. So $S \cap B \ne \emptyset$,

Using a symmetric argument, $S \cap A \ne \emptyset$.

So $\{S \cap A, S \cap B\}$ is a 2-block partition of $S$,

$$\tag 1 S = [S \cap A] \;  \bigcup \; [S \cap B]$$

To show that $S$ is discounted we'll use the theory found in this math.stackexchange post

$\quad$[Closure of a subset of a subspace of a topological space](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/268943/432081)

So, denoting the closure of $S \cap A$ in $S$ by $\overline{S \cap A}^{(S)}$, we have

$$\tag 2 [\overline{S \cap A}^{(S)}] \cap [S \cap B] = [S \cap \overline{S \cap A}] \cap  [S \cap B] $$

We have

$\quad \overline{S \cap A} \subset \overline{S} \cap \overline{A} \quad$ (the closure of an intersection of sets is always
$\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \;$ a subset of the intersection of the closures of the sets)

and since  $\overline{A}\cap B =\emptyset$, we must conclude that

$\quad [\overline{S \cap A}^{(S)}]  \; \bigcap \; [S \cap B] = \emptyset$

Symmetric logic allows us to write

$\quad [S \cap A] \; \bigcap \;[\overline{S \cap B}^{(S)}] = \emptyset$

We have shown that $S$ is disconnected. $\quad \blacksquare$