# Prove that for A $\subseteq$ B int(A) $\subseteq$ int(B) and cl(A) $\subseteq$ cl(B).

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

I have to prove that for A$\subseteq$B, int(A) $\subseteq$ int(B)and cl(A) $\subseteq$ cl(B). I hope someone here can help me out, and I apologize for any obvious mistakes. So here is my approach.

By definition, the interior of B int(B) is the largest open set contained in B. It is the union of all open sets in B: $int(A)=_{W\subseteq A:\ W\;is\;closed}W$. Thus if int(B) $\subseteq$ B and A $\subseteq$ B, then int(A) $\subseteq$ int(B).

By definition, cl(B), is the smallest closed set containing B. It is the intersection of all closed sets containing B. Thus it must hold that cl(A) $\subseteq$ cl(B), as A $\subseteq$ cl(A) and B $\subseteq$ cl(B), with A $\subseteq$ B.

Comment: I think you have some typos in your first proof. The second one: you know that $A \subseteq \mbox{cl}A$ and $B\subseteq \mbox{cl}B$ but you don't know if $\mbox{cl}A \subseteq B$ to conclude $\mbox{cl}A \subseteq \mbox{cl}B$, right?

Comment: $W$ are **open** sets with $W\subseteq A$.

Comment: For the second portion of your question, see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121236/if-a-is-a-subset-of-b-then-the-closure-of-a-is-contained-in-the-closure-o

Comment: $\text{Int}(A)$ is an open set and we have $\text{Int}(A) \subseteq A \subseteq B$;    
$\text{Cl}(B)$ is a closed set and we have $A \subseteq B \subseteq \text{Cl}(B)$

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

(a) If $U$ is an open set such that $U \subset A$ and $A\subseteq B$ then $U\subseteq B$. By definition, $\mbox{int}A$ is the union of all such open sets. Now, it is an open set, which is contained in $B$, right? What can you conclude?

(b) Analogously, if $F$ is a closed set containing $B$, then it must contain $A$. Thus, $\mbox{cl}B$ is the intersection of all such closed sets. This a closed set and it contains $B$. What can you conclude?

Answer (score 1):

Hint for the 1st. If $x\in{\rm int}A$ then exists an open $W$ with $a\in W\subseteq A$, but $A\subseteq B$ so $x\in W\subseteq B$, therefore $x\in{\rm int}B$. This settles ${\rm int}A\subseteq{\rm int}B$.

Answer (score 1):

$\operatorname{int}(A)$ is the *maximal* open set subset of $A$, so if $A \subseteq B$ it's in particular *some* open subset of $B$ too and hence a subset of the maximal open subset of $N$ which is by definition $\operatorname{int}(B)$. So $\operatorname{int}(A) \subseteq \operatorname{int}(B)$ follows.

Dually, $\overline{B}$ is the *minimal* closed superset of $B$, and hence also *some* closed superset of $A$ when $A \subseteq B$. As $\overline{A}$ is the minimal superset of $A$, again $\overline{A} \subseteq \overline{B}$ follows by minimality.

Comment: Quick question: Is it true that $\overline{A} \subseteq \overline{B} \implies$ $A \subseteq B$?

Comment: @TaylorRendon no, consider the rationals and the irrationals.

Answer (score 0):

i recommend a pointwise approach. In other words, let $a \in int(A)$. Then by definition of being in the interior, we have that $\exists U$ open, such that,
$a \in U \subseteq A$. Since $A \subseteq B$ it follows that $a \in U \subseteq B$, i.e. $a \in int(B)$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for the second question: $cl(B)$ is a closed set and $A \subset B \subset cl(B)$. So by definition and from what we are given we know that $A \subset cl(A) \subseteq B \subset cl(B)$.

So, $cl(A) \subseteq cl(B)$.

For the first question, it might be easier to approach in the following way to show that given $A \subseteq B$, $int(A) \subseteq int(B)$:

Let $x \in int(A)$. Then by definition we know that *for some* $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an open ball $B_{\epsilon}(x) \subseteq A$. Since we are given that $A \subseteq B$ and now know that $ B_{\epsilon}(x) \subseteq A$ $\implies$ $B_{\epsilon}(x) \subseteq B$ so $x \in int(B)$. So $int(A) \subseteq int(B)$.